# How to export user defined data using DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, bootstrap-4

I have a HTML table with a mixture of columns being hard coded values and others being set via java script functions dependant on user input. I can export the hard coded data fine, however it is the user defined values that I can't seem to pull through.

Here is the sample of my project:

```js
function setSquat() {
 var squatMax = document.getElementById("txtSquatInput").value;

 var values = [0.4, //0
  0.5, //1
  0.6, //2
  0.65, //3
  0.7, //4
  0.75, //5
  0.8, //6
  0.85, //7
  0.9]; //8

 var squatVal1 = values[3] * squatMax;
 var squatVal2 = values[5] * squatMax;
 var squatVal3 = values[6] * squatMax;
 var squatVal4 = values[4] * squatMax;
 var squatVal5 = values[6] * squatMax;
 var squatVal6 = values[7] * squatMax;
 var squatVal7 = values[5] * squatMax;
 var squatVal8 = values[7] * squatMax;
 var squatVal9 = values[8] * squatMax;
 var squatVal10 = values[0] * squatMax;
 var squatVal11 = values[1] * squatMax;
 var squatVal12 = values[2] * squatMax;

 //Inputting squat values
 document.getElementById("tdW1S1").innerHTML = Math.round(squatVal1);
 document.getElementById("tdW1S2").innerHTML = Math.round(squatVal2);
 document.getElementById("tdW1D3").innerHTML = Math.round(squatVal3);
 document.getElementById("tdW2D1").innerHTML = Math.round(squatVal4);
 document.getElementById("tdW2D2").innerHTML = Math.round(squatVal5);
 document.getElementById("tdW2D3").innerHTML = Math.round(squatVal6);
 document.getElementById("tdW3D1").innerHTML = Math.round(squatVal7);
 document.getElementById("tdW3D2").innerHTML = Math.round(squatVal8);
 document.getElementById("tdW3D3").innerHTML = Math.round(squatVal9);
 document.getElementById("tdW4D1").innerHTML = Math.round(squatVal10);
 document.getElementById("tdW4D2").innerHTML = Math.round(squatVal11);
 document.getElementById("tdW4D3").innerHTML = Math.round(squatVal12);

 return squatMax;
}
```

```html
<!-- Datatables links -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#531Table').DataTable({
      "stateSave": true,
      "paging": false,
      "ordering": false,
      "info": false,
      "bFilter": false,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
       'pdf',
       'excel',
      ]
     });
    });
</script>
<table class="table table-hover" id="531Table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col">Squat</th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col">Deadlift</th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col">Bench</th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col">Row</th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <!-- Sub Headings -->
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col">Sets</th>
   <th scope="col">Reps</th>
   <th scope="col">Base Number</th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col">Sets</th>
   <th scope="col">Reps</th>
   <th scope="col">Base Number</th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col">Sets</th>
   <th scope="col">Reps</th>
   <th scope="col">Base Number</th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col">Sets</th>
   <th scope="col">Reps</th>
   <th scope="col">Base Number</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr id="row1">
   <!-- Week 1 -->
   <!--Squat -->
   <th scope="row"></th>
   <td>1 - 65%</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td id="tdW1S1"></td>
   <td></td>
   <!--Deadlift -->
   <td>1 - 65%</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td id="tdW1D1"></td>
   <td></td>
   <!-- Bench -->
   <td>1 - 65%</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td id="tdW1B1"></td>
   <td></td>
   <!-- OHP -->
   <td>1 - 65%</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td id="tdW1O1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
   <!--Squat -->
   <th scope="row" class="auto-style2">Week 1</th>
   <td class="auto-style1">2 - 75%</td>
   <td class="auto-style1">5</td>
   <td id="tdW1S2" class="auto-style1"></td>
   <td class="auto-style1"></td>
   <!--Deadlift -->
   <td class="auto-style1">2 - 75%</td>
   <td class="auto-style1">5</td>
   <td class="auto-style1" id="tdW1D2"></td>
   <td class="auto-style1"></td>
   <!-- Bench -->
   <td class="auto-style1">2 - 75%</td>
   <td class="auto-style1">5</td>
   <td class="auto-style1" id="tdW1B2"></td>
   <td class="auto-style1"></td>
   <!-- OHP -->
   <td class="auto-style1">2 - 75%</td>
   <td class="auto-style1">5</td>
   <td class="auto-style1" id="tdW1O2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3" style="border-bottom: solid">
   <!--Squat -->
   <th scope="row"></th>
   <td>3 - 80%</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td id="tdW1S3"></td>
   <td></td>
   <!--Deadlift -->
   <td>3 - 80%</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td id="tdW1D3"></td>
   <td></td>
   <!-- Bench -->
   <td>3 - 80%</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td id="tdW1B3"></td>
   <td></td>
   <!-- OHP -->
   <td>3 - 80%</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td id="tdW1O3"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I've added the first three rows of the table data, two of which are just headings. The cells in question I am not getting through are in row 3 with the id values `tdW1DX`

This is an example of one of the js functions executed `onclick` - I do realize there are probably more efficient ways of doing this, however this is what works for me

I want the user to input their desired values, perform the calculation, have those placed in the table and then be able to export the table including their specific values.

Comment: If you construct user-defined part of your table (user inputs), using [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render), have your user input callbacks updating source table data (using [`rows.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()), for instance), you should be able to export your entire table all right.

Comment: having some trouble understanding this, do you mean have the user defined values put into an array onclick then add the values via `rows.add()` in the datatable script? Apologies if that is idiotic, first time using this

Comment: No apology necessary, that's me didn't make myself clear. I meant, if you update underpinning data model of your table (which is usually array of arrays/objects that correspond to your table rows sourced from local variable or via ajax) upon user input (as they fill `<input>` or choose from available options of `<select>` within table cells), you are supposed to get your data inline with view (visual table representation), and thus, able to export that data to desired format.

Comment: If you append live demo of your project sample to your post, that would be much easier to locate the root cause of your problem. At lease wider code context would be very helpful to understand how exactly you make your table editable and how do you store user inputs.

Comment: I am not fully sure on adding a live demo with jsfiddle or something like that, I have expanded the code sample to include one of the rows in question and also provided the full js function being used

Comment: @user11299053 I did achieve a variation on my desired result, however not through the datatables method. I was on a time constraint and resorted to a function which targeted the outerHTML of the table element and opened in a new window.